# What is the code/command to read/get the magnification of a DM3 file?

Tags: tags, metadata, dm-script

What is the code/command to read or get the magnification of a DM3 image?

Such as like the get size or get the name one?

`getsize(img, xsize, ysize)`

`getname(img)`?

Comment: It is usually better to ask only a single question in one post and post different questions separatetly. That way, others can more easily find answer if they have the same question. Can you please Ask the question on image-display saving as a separate post?

Comment: However, have you checked the F1 help documentation in the section *Objects:Document Object Model:Image Object* with the sub-section *Saving Images*? And then also the therein mentioned command `ImageDocumentSaveToFile()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Magnification and other acquisition related information is not a property every image has - only specific images. As such, this information is not available as a command for the `image` object, but as meta-data **stored in the image's tags**.

If you use `CTRL + D` with an image and browse to the "tags" section, you see all this meta-data organized in an expandable tree, for example:

[image: Image Tags]

How exactly this tag-tree is organized will depend on many things such as your equipment and the GMS version, whether or not the system has been calibrated etc.

All this information is then accessed via the commands described in the `TagGroup` section of the F1 help:

[image: F1 help]

But if you see the example above and would read out the number value which is selected ("Actual Magnification"), you would need to do for the front-image:

```
number mag
Image img := GetFrontImage()
TagGroup tgs = img.ImageGetTagGroup()
tgs.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Microscope Info:Actual Magnification", mag ) 
Result( "\n Mag:" + mag )
```